# Controlling Behaviour of (Compilation) Window Creation

Tags: window, compilation

How do I control whether the output buffer `*Compile*` of `M-x compile` will be shown

- in an existing window or
- in a new window by splitting an existing window

?

My problem is that the compilation buffer is opened in an existing window that I want to leave unchanged for other content.

AFAICT, this behaviour is controlled by `display-buffer`.

Answer (score 0):

The command I was looking for was `display-buffer-in-direction`. My desire use was

```
(setq display-buffer-alist
      `((,(rx bos
              (| (literal "*compilation")
                 (literal "*shell")
                 (literal "*eshell")
                 (literal "*Compile-Log")))
         display-buffer-in-direction
         (window .                      ;reference window
                 t) ;either `t' (selected window), `main', `root', or an arbitrary valid window
         (direction .
                    below)              ;`below' (window) or `bottom' (of frame)
         (window-height . 0.33)          ;absolute (10) or relative (0.3)
         )))
```